# React Native Component lifecycle methods not getting called in proper sequence

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

As per these links [React Native Component Lifecycle](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/) and [Component Lifecycle](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/), the `componentWillMount` method should get called before `render` method, but this is not the case in my project. I'm doing a `fetch` operation inside `componentWillMount`, but while that is doing stuff, the `render` method gets called before `componentWillMount` finishes. Here's my class:

```
class UserHomeScreen extends Component {
 state = { userID: '' };
 componentWillMount(){
     AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then((value) => {
         this.setState({ userID: value });
         const API_ENDPOINT= 'https://myserverAPI';
         const userID = value;
         fetch(API_ENDPOINT,{ method: "GET",
             headers:{
                 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ userID
             }
         })
             .then((response) => response.json())
             .then((responseJson) => {
                 console.log(responseJson);
                 userInfo = new UserInfo();
                 userInfo.updateValues(responseJson);
                 AsyncStorage.setItem("userInfo",JSON.stringify(userInfo),null);
                 backInfo = AsyncStorage.getItem("userInfo").then(value);
             })

     });
 }

 render(){

     return(
         <Text>hello { this.state.userID }
         </Text>
     )
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are getting called in the right order of the lifecycle. Your issue is in `fetch` because the Fetch API returns a `Promise` which is not synchronous. You can either solve this by forcing a re-render if you set the state inside the promise e.g.

```
this.setState({mode = 'loading'})
API.fetch().then(this.setState({mode = 'finished'})); // pseudo code
```

or force wait for the `Promise`. I would go with option one and set a place holder in your render method e.g.

```
 render() {
        return (
            this.state.mode == "loading" ? <div>"Loading..." </div> :
            <div>{do your stuff with the fetched response}</div> 
    }
```

Comment: Can you please have a look into my code and point out where i'm messing up things

Comment: @zulkarnainshah Use my example with the loading state. In ReactJs you will force a re-render if you change the state of a component. This is intended and the correct way to do such things.